# Id tokens vs access tokens

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization, google-oauth

[Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/why-use-access-tokens-to-secure-apis) claim I should ALWAYS use an access token to secure an API.

If I have control over both my client app and my backend API - why is it wrong to validate the id token as my authorization for my API? Id tokens signed with asymmetric keys seems secure - I don't understand how this is less secure than an access token.

Comment: OP's link is 404'ed.  Updated link [here](https://auth0.com/blog/why-should-use-accesstokens-to-secure-an-api/#:~:text=It%20enables%20you%20to%20authorize,verifying%20who%20the%20user%20is)

Answer (score 4):

It is not so much about security more more about usability and semantics. An `id_token` is supposed to represent an authentication event: it is short-lived and (primarily) designed to be one-time usage only, Those properties don't make it a good token for API usage.

Comment: I totally get your point about the semantics, but I don't quite understand why those distinctions were made in the first place.

Comment: A good access token should also be short-lived and refreshed, no?

Comment: it is not one-time usage and should be longer lived; it can be refreshed indeed, which is harder with an `id_token` (since in principle that would not be an autonomous action: it requires the user to be present)

Comment: An id_token is for a client that wants to get information about a user. An access token is for a resource server and corresponds to an authorization given to a client by the owner of the resource. In other words, the aim of each token is completely different

Answer (score 0):

Access Tokens from Auth0 implement a [Sender constraint principle](https://auth0.com/blog/identity-unlocked-explained-episode-1/), which makes tokens invalid when used by an attacker. The article you've mentioned might be a bit confusing, as it you might think they're talking about any Access Token, when they're actually talking specifically about theirs.

Keeping that in mind, most of other tokens will have the same security level, as long as they expire and can be refreshed. The difference is purpose/semantic, as mentioned in other responses.

---